# Insert non latin-1 to sql via python

Tags: python, encoding, mysql-python

I have string `somestr = '‘something’'` and I want to insert it to sql via Python using `MySQLdb`

I am already using `somestr.encode('latin-1', 'ignore')` to get latin-1 from the text but it always give following error

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2018'

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the **charset** when you create your database object like this:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db ="foodb", use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
```